# How to use __VA_ARGS__ in C or CPP

Tags: c++, macros

i have read somewhere this macro in cpp...

```
#define TR(...) __f(#__VA_ARGS__, __VA_ARGS__)
```

What does it actually mean?

Comment: Search for and read about *variadic macros*.

Comment: There's a lot of hits even in the SO search for `__VA_ARGS__`. Not a single one caught your attention?